# How to unlock dodo invaders in learn to fly 3

Tags: achievements, learn-to-fly-3

I am playing learn to fly 3 on steam and there is an achievement called :

> Old School Fun, Not So Fun

its description is this :

> Beat the highscore at Dodo Invaders

I don't know what is **Dodo Invaders**  and how to unlock it. I have search on the internet but nothing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dodo Invaders is a game you can play in the black market.

> Easter egg type minigame in the black market if you point your mouse
>   all the way to the right of the screen and click the arcade machine
>   you will start playing dodo invaders[...].

Source on [Kongregate](http://www.kongregate.com/games/light_bringer777/learn-to-fly-3/comments?sort=best), down the first page.